# Create view changes "... is null" to isnull() - but then doesn't work

Tags: mysql, view, group-concat, having, isnull

I have a query like this:

```
select a.*, (select group_concat(b.name) from b where b.id = a.id) as b_concat
from a
having b_concat is null
```

This works correctly when executed directly.  But I get errors when I put it into a view.

The 'create view ...' statement works fine and creates the view.  But when I do "select * from my_view", I get error:

Error Code: 1356
View 'my_db.my_view' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

I then look at my view definition and mysql has changed "having b_concat is null" to "having isnull(b_concat)" - so in the view it now has:

```
select a.*, (select group_concat(b.name) from b where b.id = a.id) as b_concat
from a
having isnull(b_concat)
```

When I copy that sql and execute it directly, and I get error:

Unknown column 'b_concat' in 'having clause'

Question ...

Is there a way to force mysql to *not* convert to "isnull()" - or maybe a way to make mysql know that "b_concat" is a derived field when it's inside isnull() ?

Or is there something else I should do?

Note - The table relationship is one 'a' to many 'b'.

Thanks,
Josh